What is the point of two enable signals in PT6957 LED driver?
I have a 48 x 16 matrix LED display E-MOTIVE Q-B-069B (no datasheet), and during reverse engineering I found 4 off PT6957 there.

PT6957 is 16-bit shift register, latched with constant current drives. For now it looks one of PT6957 is used to drive rows, and others for columns.
Looking in the datasheet of PT6957, there are two ENABLE signals ENA and ENB.
See the diagram:

What is the point of two enable signals? Does it have any practical benefits?

Just for convenience? Some generic logic chips have this too? One might be your device's global enable, the other may be your bus multiplexer's enable, etc?

The package had 2 pins free.  Allows ANDing of two control sources.

From the schematic I can see the ENA looks like a global ENABLE i.e. if it's logic-1 then the NOR gates output logic-0 which apparently drive the LEDs through the current limiter/comparator.
If ENA = 0 and ENB = 1 the latching driver seems to be driving the LEDs.
ENA can be used for testing purposes i.e. during production testing if you apply ENA = 1 all the LEDs will be on.
